# How to restrict the validation in Play wizard?

Tags: java, validation, playframework-2.0, wizard

I use Play Framework 2.2.1 and I implemeted my own wizard from this [sample](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/java/forms/app/models/User.java). But I have a problem with validation because user defines more "Address"-es and in different steps in my wizard.

Here is my Person class:

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

public class Person {

    @Valid
    private Address permanentAddress;    // restrict the validation to the Step1

    @Valid
    private Address invoiceAddress;      // restrict the validation to the Step2

    // ...
}
```

Here is my Address class:

```
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;

public class Address {

    @Required(groups = { Step1.class, Step2.class })
    private String street;

    @Required(groups = { Step1.class, Step2.class })
    private String number;

    // ...
}
```

The validation in Step1 fails now, because attributes "street" and "number" are null/empty in "invoiceAddress". Here is snippet from my Controller:

```
private static Result handleStep1Submission() {
    Form<Person> filledForm = form(Person.class, Step1.class).bindFromRequest();

    if (filledForm.hasErrors()) {
         // this now fails because "invoiceAddress.street" and
         // "invoiceAddress.number" are null/empty
    } else {
         // ...
}
```

How to restrict the validation to the Step1 or Step2 in this case?

Answer (score 2):

Good question. I can think of two (inelegant) ways around your problem. Unfortunately I don't think Play's validation code natively supports this situation:

#### Option 1: Ad-hoc validation

This is the recommended approach if you want to enforce some nifty validation rules that Play won't give you out of the box (e.g cross-field validation). If you define a `validate` method in your form class, Play will find it via reflection and call it after all the validation annotations have been processed:

```
public class Person {

    // New field, gets populated by a hidden field in your HTML form
    private int step;

    private Address permanentAddress;    // restrict the validation to the Step1

    private Address invoiceAddress;      // restrict the validation to the Step2

    // ...

    public String validate() {

        if (step == 1) {
            // manually validate permanentAddress
        }

        if (step == 2) {
            // manually validate invoiceAddress
        }
    }
}
```

Because all of the validation is now ad-hoc and not annotation-driven, you can then remove your annotations from `Address`:

```
public class Address {

    private String street;

    private String number;

    // ...
}
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms) for more information about registering a validate method.

#### Option 2: Subclass Address

If the first option doesn't sound that appealing to you, you could create `Address` subclasses (perhaps extracting out an interface in the process):

```
public interface Address {

    public String getStreet();

    public String getNumber();

    // ...
}
```

```
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;

public class PermanentAddress implements Address {

    @Required(groups = {Step1.class})
    private String street;

    @Required(groups = {Step1.class})
    private String number;

    // ...
}
```

```
import play.data.validation.Constraints.Required;

public class InvoiceAddress implements Address {

    @Required(groups = {Step2.class})
    private String street;

    @Required(groups = {Step2.class})
    private String number;

    // ...
}
```

```
import javax.validation.Valid;

public class Person {

    @Valid
    private PermanentAddress permanentAddress;

    @Valid
    private InvoiceAddress invoiceAddress;

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank You for answer. I considered your both options. **1.option:** I didn't want to split validation into 2 parts (annotation and method _validate()_). **2.option:** I didn't want to change my model and repeat the same annotations on "the same fields", but I implemented this 2.option. :(